# Deploying the GraphAware friendship-counter example to some standalone neo4j server

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, graphaware

I'm giving the GraphAware's example a try to understand how it works. But I'm having trouble running their [friendship counter example](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/examples/friendship-strength-counter-module).

To this end, I've built the mentioned example package using `mvn package` which generated the following jar files:

- friendship-strength-counter-module-3.1.0.45-SNAPSHOT.jar
- friendship-strength-counter-module-3.1.0.45-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
- friendship-strength-counter-module-3.1.0.45-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
- graphaware-friendship-strength-counter-module-3.1.0.45-SNAPSHOT.jar

Then I copied the first file alongside GraphAware framework-server-community's [latest version](http://products.graphaware.com/download/framework-server-community/latest) into the plugins directory of the neo4j. Then I added the following line to `neo4j.conf` file:

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware
```

and restarted the neo4j server. When I go to `http://localhost:7474/graphaware/friendship/strength` I can see that the REST API part of the code is working since it returns `0` and also it creates a `:FriendshipCounter` node on the server.

But it seems that the `FriendshipStrengthCounter` class is not registered as a `TransactionEventHandler` since when I create the following two nodes:

```
CREATE (n)-[:FRIEND_OF{strength: 2}]->(m);
```

the counter is not updated. Can someone please tell me where did I make a mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try enabling the framework and the module by adding those lines to your `neo4j.conf` :

```
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

#COUNTER becomes the module ID:
com.graphaware.module.COUNTER.1=com.graphaware.example.module.FriendshipStrengthModuleBootstrapper
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but could you please include some reference or documentation on what these are and how to use them? For instance, what's `.1` part?

Comment: yes, well the .1 part is explained in the framework documentation. but we'll add some doc in the counter example